# Can I use GUI/UI interface instead of command line on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I just created a aws lightsail instance, which includes nodejs under Ubuntu, and it is quickly setup, which looks cool.

However I only find the command line operation. I still cannot find the GUI, as it is uncomfortable to edit file through command line.

Any idea of how can I use GUI on it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world.

No, You cannot use the GUI/UI to edit the files on the Amazon Lightsail instances. You can connect to the server using winscp software and edit the web root files on your machine.

To edit the files out side web root you have to rely on the editors suggested by David J Eddy

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like I'm a bit late in answering this question, but yes, there is a way to edit files using a GUI.

To do this, install an FTP client on your own computer (not Lightsail server). Popular examples include FileZilla and Cyberduck, and both have free versions.

Once downloaded, you just type in your Server IP address and link your .pem keychain file (should be downloaded from lightsail.aws.amazon.com).

With this new software, you can edit files from your instance and the file structure on your own computer.
[image: image of ftp software]

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The Ubuntu flavors used in LightSail are of the 'Server' variety. You may not like the idea of editing via the CLI but, honestly, learn it. VIM, eMacs, Nano, etc. Find an editor you can handle and learn it as well as you can. This will help you much later.